# How to change the names in matplotlib legend box?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

I have file in.txt, which have many rows. and 1-20 columns (it's undefined). and contains numbers.

I draw a graphic with this code

```
y=np.loadtxt('in.txt')
t=np.arange(len(y))*1
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title(r'in')
plt.grid(1)
plt.plot(t,y, label = 'in')
plt.legend(borderpad = 0.1, labelspacing = 0.1)
plt.show()
```

[It is what I have now (in this example I have 10 columns in file in.txt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scCGP.png)

But, rather than all names in legend are "in", I want names like "1", "2", "3" etc. (from 1 to n, where n is a number of columns in my in.txt file)

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is by plotting each line in an iteration of a for-loop. For example:

```
y = np.random.random((3,5))  # create fake data
t = np.arange(len(y))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title(r'in')
plt.grid(1)
for col_indx in range(y.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(t, y[:,col_indx], label = col_indx)
plt.legend(borderpad = 0.1, labelspacing = 0.1)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, and I'd recommend this solution in your case, is to use the optional arguments of the call to [`plt.legend`](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html). Like this:

```
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.legend(range((len(y)))
```

Check out the doc-string of `plt.legend` when you want to go a bit more advanced.

If you wanted to start labelling using a 1-based index, rather than zero-based, don't forget to add `+1` in the label and the range ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking advantage of the broadcasting in `plot` for the x/y, but the kwargs do not also get broadcast.  Either

```
x = np.arange(25)
y = np.random.rand(25, 6)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for j, _y in enumerate(y.T, start=1):
    ax.plot(x, _y, label=str(j))
ax.legend(borderpad=0.1, labelspacing=0.1)
```

or

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lns = ax.plot(x, y)
labels = [str(j) for j in range(1, y.shape[1] + 1)]
ax.legend(handles=lns, labels=labels, borderpad=0.1, labelspacing=0.1)
```